# Flying 1 day before Schengen visa starts

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas

I just received my Schengen visa and it starts on the 25th of August, however I had applied for it to start on the 24th.

Is it possible to fly on the 24th, if I will arrive and be entering the Schengen area on the 25th?

Would I face any issues boarding the flight on the 24th?

Comment: So to summarize: Your plane will arrive in the Schengen area on the 25th and your visa is valid from the 25th. Is that correct? If so, why do you think it could be a problem?

Comment: I would be worried about unexpected changes, such as my flight being cancelled and me being transferred to a flight that arrives earlier. Or if my flight has a stop, the stop being skipped due to weather and arriving early. Or tail winds.

Comment: Collateral question: if you arrive late on the 24th, can you get away with stalling until midnight to go to the control booth?  (Probably depends on which airport)

Comment: Stalling does _not_ work we have covered that in the past, you will look suspicious as hell. The question as is can't be answered, it needs more details.

Comment: I will be flying on the 24th and arriving on the 25th. Thank you for your time and responses, everyone.

Comment: @WGroleau if the flight is scheduled to arrive before midnight, the airline will refuse boarding for the lack of a valid visa.